# Resizing browser windows to 50% of the screen using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know of a way to resize 2 windows to 50% of the screen using Selenium? Or something similar if it can't do it. I'm using Python and Chromium but again, if there is something better I am open to ideas.

Comment: I know how to do it in C# but not in python. You can use System.Window.Form.Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds and in returns System.Drawing.Rectangle class and from there you can get the screen dimension and put it in webdriver size method

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for 50%

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '0.50'")
```

- `0.50` means - 50% Zoom
- `1.50` means - 150% Zoom

Comment: I think the question is to set the screen size of the actual windows rather than the content within the windows

Answer (score 0):

You can get the window size by

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int height = size.getHeight();
int width = size.getWidth();
```

And set the window size by

```
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(width/2, height);
```